# How to pass parameters to ms access to get the data back

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I am new to ms access..Can anybody help me in sending parameters to queries and get back the data(with an example)..i am using C# as coding language(Asp.Net)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Code please? Show some code that you have written already?

Comment: Retagged from ms to ms-access. Tag ms is used rarely and inconsistently.

Answer (score 2):

You will need the following using statement:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
```

Example:

```
string ConnString = "Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|Northwind.mdb";
string SqlString = @"Select * From Contacts 
                    Where FirstName = @FirstName And LastName = @LastName";
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
{
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", txtLastName.Text);
        conn.Open();
        using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Response.Write(reader["FirstName"].ToString() + " " + reader["LastName"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET provides an [AccessDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e5545e1.aspx) control that greatly simplifies this. You can use it as in the example below and bind the results directly to a gridview.

```
<asp:AccessDataSource
  id="InvoiceAccessDataSource"
  DataFile="~/App_Data/Northwind.mdb"
  runat="server"
  SelectCommand="[Employee Sales By Country]"
  SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Beginning Date" Type="DateTime" defaultValue="1/1/1997" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Ending Date" Type="DateTime" defaultValue="1/31/1997" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>

<asp:GridView
  id="InvoiceGridView"
  runat="server"
  AutoGenerateColumns="True"
  DataSourceid="InvoiceAccessDataSource" />
```