# Displaying a single row from access database in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

i have a project, and part of it asks the user to input the ID of the patient to show his/her details
This is my code

```
        sConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=hospital database.accdb";
        dbConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnection);
        dbConn.Open();
        sql = "SELECT * FROM Patients";
        dbCmd = new OleDbCommand();
        dbCmd.CommandText = sql;
        dbCmd.Connection = dbConn;

        dbReader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();


        listBox1.Items.Clear();




        if (dbReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (dbReader.Read())
            {

                if (dbReader["PatientID"] != DBNull.Value)
                {

                    int anInteger;
                    anInteger = Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text);
                    anInteger = int.Parse(textBox7.Text);

                    if (anInteger == 101)
                    {

                    }

                }


            }
        }
```

in the IF statement, i dont know what to write in it, to display on the row of the patient with this ID only

Please Help!!

Comment: Why don't you just query for the one patient info that you want instead of querying all of them?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting all rows, it is much more efficient to filter the one row you are looking for using a parameter and modifying your SQL statement as follows.

```
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Patients WHERE PatientID = [pID]";
    dbCmd = new OleDbCommand();
    dbCmd.CommandText = sql;
    dbCmd.Connection = dbConn;
    dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pID", 101);
    dbReader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I would also suggest looking into the "using" clause. Here's a SO [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994463/how-to-pass-parameters-to-ms-access-to-get-the-data-back).

Comment: +1 with two very minor comments: (1) Missing `)` on `AddWithValue`. (2) With ACE/Jet OLEDB it is more common to use `?` as the parameter placeholders/names since the provider ignores the actual *names* and only uses the *order* in which they are specified.

Comment: Thanks Gord. I guess my usage of brackets is a left over from the VBA days.

Answer (score 1):

```
  sql = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Patients WHERE PatientID = @PID";
    dbCmd = new OleDbCommand();
    dbCmd.CommandText = sql;
    dbCmd.Connection = dbConn;
    dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PID", 101);
    Int32 Cnt = dbCmd.ExecuteScalar();
if ( Cnt > 0)
{
// Do Something
}
else  { // Do something}
```

Answer (score 0):

you  have to use a variable to be sure that your ID was found and  and `break;` to exit your loop once it was found

```
if (dbReader.HasRows)
        {
           bool found  = false;  
            while (dbReader.Read())
            {

                if (dbReader["PatientID"] != DBNull.Value)
                {

                    int anInteger;
                    anInteger = Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text);
                    anInteger = int.Parse(textBox7.Text);

                    if (anInteger == 101)
                    {
                        found = true ;  Break; 

                    }

                }


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int anInteger = Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text);        
    sConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=hospital database.accdb";
    dbConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnection);
    dbConn.Open();
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Patients where PatientID=@PatientID";
    dbCmd = new OleDbCommand();
    dbCmd.CommandText = sql;
    dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientID",anInteger);
    dbCmd.Connection = dbConn;

    dbReader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();


    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    while (dbReader.Read())
    {
       //now display the reader values here : sample
       //TextBox1.Text=dbReader["name"].ToString();
    }
```